# why would enterprises use Struts 1 and Spring together

Tags: java, spring, struts, enterprise

I'm new to Struts 1 and Spring, and I'm curious as to why enterprises integrate them both when they could use either one as a standalone framework. 
I also do know that Spring has advantages over using Struts 1 such as IOC and DI, so what gives?

My guess would be migration from Struts 1 to Spring, and the use of both is part of the process such as [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-spring-hibernate-integration-example/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts (1 or 2) is *only* a web layer, while Spring includes (more or less) everything.

Some people simply prefer the Struts model of the web layer (I prefer S2 over Spring MVC, but barely), some systems grew organically, Struts 1 existed before Spring MVC, etc.

It was very common to use Spring as glue but use Struts as the web layer.

Comment: thanks Dave, clear and concise!

Answer (score 1):

The last release of Struts 1.x was in 2008 and Struts 1.x [is no longer maintained](http://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html).  While it might be possible to integrate Struts 1.x with newer versions of Spring, I certainly wouldn't recommend it and you're very unlikely to see new projects start this way.

If you're currently working in a codebase that uses Spring + Struts 1.x, it's most likely an older code base where a significant chunk of functionality is tied to Struts 1.x.  For example, all of the application logic is written the [Controllers](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/tiles/Controller.html) or [Actions](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html).  Spring was probably added after a lot of the code was written and it was cost prohibitive to migrate from Struts 1 to Spring MVC.